# information gathering on a person

Tags: information-gathering

How would a hacker go about gathering information on a real person with a minimum amount of details about him?

Details known:

1. Name
2. Face

Comment: face?  Is this an image they have possession of or have they simply seen the person before?

Comment: tell me both cases

Comment: There are multiple guides on the internet on how to dox people. They are easily found by googling "how to dox" or "guide to doxing".

Comment: thanks tom.will look into into it.is it legit?

Comment: @TomK. That will probably get a bunch of troll guides and "how to deliver a million pizzas to your enemies". If OP wants professional information, he should search for digital OSINT techniques.

Comment: What information do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

**The process of gathering information on an individual from public sources is called OSINT.**

This depends on too many factors. You may be able to do a reverse image search of the face on various search engines, but it will be unlikely to return useful results. With the name, you can look them up on Google or Bing, or one of many flesh search engines such as Pipl or a paid alternative (there are many). These do more comprehensive searches. The face can come in useful here to verify that a result is actually the correct person and not someone else who happens to have the same name.

If you truly know nothing but the face and name, then you'll probably be out of luck if the above doesn't work for you. If you have a little more information, such as their line of work, then you can do searches on domain-specific resources. If your target is a government employee for example, you can narrow down your search significantly as many government employees in many countries are listed in public. Knowing exactly where to look for each "kind" of person takes trial and error, and often just experience.